# Android Studio bug

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I need to test an application on Android Studio, but my virtual machine is not creating correctly and the studio does not see my phone, even though the debug mode is enabled on it. How can I test my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the android developer official site [how to connect the real device and run app](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app). And for create virtual device [follow this tutorial from the official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd)

Comment: Oh, I still have problem

Comment: What type of problem you faced. Take a screenshot here!!

Comment: Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager
Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD
Change "Graphics" to "Software". You can try these steps and then run again.

Comment: Try to create a new virtual device and then run the app. If still have a problem let me know.